# how to use connection pooling to reuse store.connect() in java mail API for multiple users

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, connection-pooling

I have used connection pooling to reuse store.connect(). It works for single user but for multiple users it is not working.

For multiple users it takes the 1st loaded user data for all other users.
How to fix this.

Below is the code,

```
public class EmailListingController {

    private static EmailListingController instance = null;
    private static Store store = null;

    public EmailListingController() {
        super();
    }

    private EmailListingController(String host, String mailstoreType, String username, String originalPassword,
            int port, boolean auth, boolean security, User user) throws MessagingException {
        System.out.println("props + store connect");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.store.protocol", mailstoreType);
        properties.put("mail.imaps.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.imaps.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", security);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
        store = session.getStore();
        store.connect(username, originalPassword);
    }

    public static synchronized EmailListingController getInstance(String host, String mailstoreType, String username,
            String originalPassword, int port, boolean auth, boolean security, User user) throws MessagingException {
        System.out.println("instance");
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new EmailListingController(host, mailstoreType, username, originalPassword, port, auth, security,
                    user);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @GetMapping("/inbox/{userId}")
    public ResponseEntity test(@PathVariable("userId") Integer id) {
        Optional<User> user = userService.findById(id);
        List<Email> emailList = new ArrayList<Email>();
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            String username = user.get().getUserName();
            String pwd = user.get().getPassword();

            EmailListingController client = EmailListingController.getInstance(host, mailstoreType, username,
                    pwd, port, auth, security, user.get());
            Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");
            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            String from;String subject;String message1;String cc;String to;String bcc;
            String[] toArray = null;String[] ccArray = null;String[] bccArray = null;Email email2;
            FetchProfile fp1 = new FetchProfile();
            fp1.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
            fp1.add(IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.FLAGS);
            fp1.add(IMAPFolder.FetchProfileItem.CONTENT_INFO);
            fp1.add(UIDFolder.FetchProfileItem.UID);
            folder.fetch(folder.getMessages(), fp1);
            for (Message message : folder.getMessages()) {
                System.out.println("message" + message.getSubject());
            }
            return new ResponseEntity(emailList, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!